# contenteditable div in a table cell with text-ellipsis not working in IE11

Tags: css

I have the following markup in a table cell:

```
<td class="name">
  <img width="22" height="22" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/radium/image/upload/c_fill,g_face,h_22,w_22/v1/default_avatars/large.jpg">
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
    This is a very long piece of text we want to use an ellipsis with   
  </div>
</td>
```

I have the following style to add an ellipsis to long text in a table cell:

```
table tr td.name {
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin: 0 !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gufowu/4/edit?html,css,output) that shows it working.

It works in most browsers but We have to support IE11 and in IE11, it cuts off all the text and just shows the ellipsis.

The problem seems to be that the table cell contains div that is `contenteditable` and turning that attribute to false makes everything display fine but we want these cells to be editable so we need a workaround.

Is it possible to make this work in IE11?

Comment: "it cuts off all the text and just shows the ellipsis"... that's kind of the point of ellipsis?

Comment: I had not recreated the problem properly.  I've updated the question and the jsbin

Comment: I think OP meant it replaces the content with ellipsis, instead of truncating the overflow.

Comment: Just a heads up, on chrome mobile, the elision is fine, but trying to edit the content breaks, as only the visible text is rendered as edit content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of ellipsis on a parent container of a contentEditable also doesn't work for me in Safari, the ellipsis ends up inside the editable content:

[image: Safari behaviour with jsbin example]

I expect this is a conflict of features that were never really designed to work together. You would be better off having a "read-only" view of the ellipsised (elipsed?) content in the table cell, and open a pop-up editor when someone clicks on it.

If you really must have the text editable inside the cell, you could toggle between read-only `ellipsis` and `contentEditable` modes in javascript.

This [jQuery example](http://jsbin.com/lonosahate/3/edit?html,css,js,output) works in IE11 and Safari (other browsers not tested). The caret is jumped to the end on focus because the `contentEditable` div was not able to observe the position of the cursor at the time the click action occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the `white-space: nowrap;` property and that should do the trick.

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vimibakowe/3/edit?html,css,output)**

The other option is to increase the width like this:

```
max-width: 500px;
```

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/camulapenu/1/edit?css,output)**

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works in my IE11 ... Removing the `white-space: nowrap;` breaks the functionality in all browsers.

Comment: I had not recreated the problem properly.  I've updated the question and the jsbin